# How to approach this problem? Python returning objects from a function from a list

Tags: python, windows, function, return

I am using prompt_toolkit to create a little interface that displays notes. The question doesn't really have to do with this particular matter, but I have come across it several times while learning python.

The thing is, I have this function that creates the container:

```
def create_new(hint):
    return Frame(title="%s" %  hint, body=Label("%s" % hint))
hints = ["hint1", "hint2", "..."]
root_container = VSplit(
    [
        HSplit(
            [
                Window(
                    content=FormattedTextControl(get_statusbar_text),
                    height=D.exact(1),
                    style="class:status",
                ),
                #Frame(title="The custom window", body=Label("hello\ntest"), width=50),
                do_stuff_to_display_more_frames()
            ],
        ),

    ]
)
```

As you can understand from the code, what I want is to return that function as many times as the content of the list. But all my attempts have failed:

```
[create_new(i) for i in hints]
ValueError: Not a container object: [<prompt_toolkit.widge..>,<prompt...>,<prompt>]
```

It also won't let me use a for loop:

```
for i in hints:
      create_new(i)
```

Is there any solution for the return function to return all functions properly:

```
Frame (title = "hint1" ...
Frame (title = "hint2" ...
```

**EDIT**
@Barmar, there it is, but the problem is not the programa if i put `create_new("hint1")` it works perfectly.

```
HSplit(
  File "C:\Users\Z\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\prompt_toolkit\layout\containers.py", line 290, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "C:\Users\Z\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\prompt_toolkit\layout\containers.py", line 216, in __init__
    self.children = [to_container(c) for c in children]
  File "C:\Users\Z\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\prompt_toolkit\layout\containers.py", line 216, in <listcomp>
    self.children = [to_container(c) for c in children]
  File "C:\Users\Z\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\prompt_toolkit\layout\containers.py", line 2678, in to_container
    raise ValueError("Not a container object: %r" % (container,))
ValueError: Not a container object: [<prompt_toolkit.widgets.base.Frame object at 0x000001A100EBA790>, <prompt_toolkit.widgets.base.Frame object at 0x000001A103356A90>, <prompt_toolkit.widgets.base.Frame object at 0x000001A103365E50>]
```

Comment: Can you show the full traceback of the error?

Comment: `ValueError: Not a container object: [<prompt_toolkit.widgets.base.Frame object at 0x000001A100EBA790>, <prompt_toolkit.widgets.base.Frame object at 0x000001A103356A90>, <prompt_toolkit.widgets.base.Frame object at 0x000001A103365E50>]` I think the problem is that is inside a list, and the `HSplit` need one lines

Comment: That's not a standard Python error, it's specific to the Prompt toolkit.

Comment: That's not a traceback. It should show the hierarchy of function calls that lead to the error.

Comment: `body` has to be a container. Maybe `Label` isn't a container.

Comment: Like a say If i do `create_new("hint1")` it works, the problem is to do it recursively

Comment: The question definitely has to do with the details of the prompt toolkit.

Comment: Okay! But I still believe that the question is related to Python itself, because when I do I do it with a for loop outside the function, it does give the result I want.

Comment: The error seems to be happening in `HSplit()`. I have no idea what that does, but I don't think it wants its argument to be a list.

Comment: The `HSplit()`  gets containers (an object from the prompt_toolkit)  like `Window` or `Frame` the point is create this Frames in a dinamic way, not doing `create_new(hints[0])`and the line below `create_new(hints[1])`